# JavaFX waiting user input's text without any textfield

Tags: java, javafx

I am trying to get user input's text without any textfield with JavaFX (not with console) but I am stuck with the code. Basically what I would like to do is during the login page user will receive a random string of OTP automatically generated from a token USB by pressing a button in the USB and the string will be automatically received with the login page when the form is active without any textfield involved.

The code for the presenter that I can come up now is like this:

```
public class LoginBoxPresenterFinal implements Initializable {

...
    public void initialize(URL arg0, ResourceBundle arg1) {
    ....
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);  
        String otp = reader.nextLine();
        System.out.println(otp);
}}
```

This code is wrong actually as the Scanner will only receive the input in the Eclipse's console and it will not show the login page until i type something in the console and press Enter button.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: I think your only option is to listen to [onKeyPressed](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Scene.html#setOnKeyPressed-javafx.event.EventHandler-) and keep track of the characters one-by-one.

Comment: @sillyfly the problem is that this input is not from what user's typed  but it is automatically generated by this token USB, and also if using onKeyPressed if I have another textfield for username it will also be captured.

Comment: Presumably the USB token operates like a keyboard, sending key presses. If it works differently then your question should probably include more info about how it actually works.

Comment: @sillyfly i think it works like keyboard typing in this case with Enter button is pressed in the end. I am still new with JavaFX so I don't know how to receive the user's text input with onKeyPressed. Could you help?

Answer (score 2):

i can help you Sir.

```
Stage s = new Stage(StageStyle.DECORATED);//suppose this is your stage
    s.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);
    p = new Pane();
    p.setStyle("-fx-background-color: yellow");
    s.setScene(new Scene(p,150,150));
    s.show();
    s.addEventFilter(KeyEvent.KEY_RELEASED, new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(KeyEvent t) {
            if(t.getCode().equals(KeyCode.ENTER)){
               //this is when the user clicks enter meaning he is done or something
                //like that
            }else{
                //here the code detect keycodes other than enter to get them
                KeyCode kc = t.getCode();
                //now store kc somewhere and use it.
            }
            t.consume();//the consume here is because i do not want
            //the TextField to hear about the keypressed.
            //remove it if you want it to be notified
        }
    });
```

This is how the code works since you do not want the `TextField` to interrupt
call add an eventfliter on your `Stage` and the Stage will be the first to be notified of any key press by ur USB keyboard. That is all, very easy

Hope it helps